# Can 2 dimensional input be applied to SVM?

Tags: machine-learning, svm

When considering Support Vector Machine, in an take in multiple inputs. Can each of these inputs be a vector??
What i am trying to say is, can the input be a 2 dimensional vector??

Comment: It's not clear what you mean. Is the input to SVM a vector? yes, that's true for most ML algorithms. Multiple vectors? yes, training happens on > 1 data point. 2D? yes. Somehow, several 2D vectors at once? not clear what that means. Please clarify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly. Yes, SVM can take multiple inputs. My suggestion for handling a vector as a feature would be to expand it out. For example,

```
x0 = (1,2)       x0 = 1
x1 = .4  ----->  x1 = 2
x2 = 0           x2 = .4
                 x3 = 0
```

If this does not capture all of the characteristics of the vector that are important, then you may want to add other features (like magnitude of the vector) as well.

Comment: ok, so if one of the input is 2d then it is expanded, yes, this is exactly what i wanted to know...  thanks a lot